# MYSQL Select query from attendance table between two dates get sundays as Over Time

Tags: sql, mysql

I have 3 table attendance, attTable, holidays

Table 1
attendance with 2 columns (empid, attdate)

| empid | attdate |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | 2023-01-01 08.30 |
| 101 | 2023-01-01 17.30 |
| 201 | 2023-01-01 08.30 |
| 201 | 2023-01-01 17.30 |

Table 2
holidays with 3 columns (hid, date_holiday, notes)

| hid | date_holiday | notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 2023-01-05 00.00 | national day |
| 02 | 2023-05-01 00.00 | May Day |
| 03 | 2023-06-30 00.00 | special |
| 04 | 2023-07-17 17.30 | gov holiday |

I'm getting records from attendance table and saving into attTable (filtered data)
Using below code

```
truncate table attTable;

insert into attTable
select 
  emp_id as 'EMPID', 
  min(attdate) as 'TimeIN', 
  max(attdate) as 'TimeOUT', 
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, min(attdate), max(attdate)) - 9*60 as 'OTM', 
  sl_no as SN 
from mytable 
group by EMPID, date_format(attdate, '%Y-%m-%d') 
order by EMPID;
```

1. this will calculate over 9 hours as OT
2. is it possible to include when it is sunday all working as OT(if 10 hours worked 10 hours as OT)
3. include date_holidays columns from hoilidays table (if match that day make it all hours as OT)

or is it correct way updating table after inserted

Comment: Strictly, there should only be one question per question

Comment: dear, my question is 1 with 3 conditions.

Comment: Do not use `date_format(attdate, '%Y-%m-%d')`, use `CAST(attdate AS DATE)` instead.

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), #5 and #3.

Comment: `from mytable` - not described. Does this is `attendance`? If so then `sl_no as SN` is not described.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a left-join to match the attendance dates with holiday dates and use the `datename` function to check if the attendance date is Sunday.

```
select 
  att.emp_id as                   'EMPID', 
  min(att.attdate) as             'TimeIN', 
  max(att.attdate) as             'TimeOUT', 
  hld.date_holiday is not null or
  dayname(max(att.attdate)) = 'Sunday' as 'is_holyday_or_sunday', -- you may remove this column if not needed
  case 
  when 
    dayname(max(att.attdate)) = 'Sunday' or 
    hld.date_holiday is not null 
    then TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, min(att.attdate), max(att.attdate))
  else -- greatest is used in case working hours is less than 9 hours to avoid negative ot value
    greatest(TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, min(att.attdate), max(att.attdate)) - 9*60, 0) 
  end as 'OTM'
from attendance att left join holidays hld
on cast(att.attdate as date) = cast(hld.date_holiday as date)
group by att.emp_id, cast(att.attdate as date) , hld.date_holiday
order by att.emp_id
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/jg2qa1_6)

It's not clear what sl_no column is, see @Akina's comment.